# Game Center - sending and receiving data with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios10, game-center

I am trying to send the following structure from one player to another:

```
struct GamePacket {
    var action: String
    var pointArray: [CGPoint]
}
```

I'm having a hard time figuring out the correct way to convert the `GamePacket` to `Data` and back again.

Here is the code I have so far for **sending** packets:

```
func send(packet: GamePacket) {
    //convert GamePacket to Data here
    let data = Data.init()

    var remotePlayerArray = [GKPlayer]()

    if let currentPlayer = self.currentPlayer, let match = self.match, let playerArray = self.match?.players {
        for player in playerArray {
            if player != currentPlayer {
                remotePlayerArray.append(player)
            }
        }

        do {
            try match.send(data, to: remotePlayerArray, dataMode: GKMatchSendDataMode.reliable)
        }
        catch {
            print("connectionError")
        }
    }
}
```

And the code for **receiving**:

```
func match(_ match: GKMatch, didReceive data: Data, fromRemotePlayer player: GKPlayer) {
    //convert Data to GamePacket here
}
```

From some samples written in `ObjectiveC`, I managed to convert the `GamePacket` to `Data` using something simmilar to the following:

```
let data = NSData(bytes: &packet, length: MemoryLayout<GamePacket>.size) as Data
```

However, I can't figure out how to convert the `Data` back to a `GamePacket` on the receiving end, nor am I sure this is the correct way to do it.

Any help is greatly apreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick and dirty solution would be something like this:

```
func encodeGamePacket(packet: GamePacket) -> NSData {
    return NSData(bytes: &gamePacket, length: MemoryLayout<GamePacket>.size)
}

func decodeGamePacket(data: NSData) -> GamePacket? {
    var tempBuffer:GamePacket? = nil
    data.getBytes(&tempBuffer, length: MemoryLayout<GamePacket>.size)
    return tempBuffer
}
```

I have not messed with direct addresses myself under swift yet, so I am not entirely sure whether this is the best approach. Note that I used an optional return type, you can design this differently in your code (maybe add some checks, unwrap the variable and return it or throw an exception when the checks fail).

Alternatively you could design a method that writes your `GamePacket` into a `String` (for readability, for example), which you can in turn transform into `NSData` (String has a `data` method) or you turn `GamePacket` into an `NSCoding` compliant class that offers methods to convert itself into `NSData` as well.

Answer (score 4):

### Use `Codable`

```
struct GamePacket: Codable {
  var action: String
  var pointArray: [CGPoint]
}
```

Then you can convert to `Data` easily:

```
func save<T: Encodable>(_ item: T, to url: URL) throws -> Data {
  let encoder = JSONEncoder()
  return try encoder.encode(item)
}
func load<T: Decodable>(from data:Data) throws -> T {
  let decoder = JSONDecoder()
  let item = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
  return item
}
```

Comment: Just as quick, but a little less dirty. :)

Comment: I was just facing the same problem and was happy to find your solution @Tyler A.
, thanks for that! Unfortunately I got two problems left:

1. I didn't know what to to with the URL parameter as I'm trying to save the decoded data in a variable like `var message = load(from: data)`

2. When doing as described in 1 I'm getting the error `Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred`

Can you help out?